# SQL How to select all values including null?

Tags: sql

So I am trying to select all the values including null, and I know there are a few threads about this topic but it's all not working for me, or I don't know how to implemend it. Anyways, I have to get the lowest price of all colors. And when I try the query I have right now It's getting the lowest price of all the colors excluding null. But I also want the lowest price when the color is null.
this is the query I have now:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM plant p
inner JOIN (SELECT Color, min(price) minPrice
            from  plant
            group by color                                          
        ) b on p.price = b.minPrice and
                p.color= b.color
order by plantcode;
```

How to fix the query that it selects all values including null?

Comment: You should try using a left outer join instead of an inner join, see if that works for you.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Comment: Have you tried the NVL Function ? https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp

Comment: @Tim, NVL? Product specific function, for a question with no dbms specified.

Comment: @jarlh the link I posted shows the usual dbms

Comment: If I change the inner join to a left join it wont work

Comment: Still no sample data. Do you want us to guess what you are expecting?

Comment: How do I post sample data?

Comment: I think the question is pretty clear, instead of all values excluding null I want them with null..data is not required in this case

Comment: @Alegou20 You want the `minPrice` in the inner query to return `NULL` values? If yes, you cannot use that field in the `JOIN` condition, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited version of cars10's answer:

```
SELECT  p.* FROM plant p
inner JOIN(SELECT Color, min(COALESCE(price,0)) minPrice
            from  plant group by color                                          
        ) b on COALESCE(p.price,0) = b.minPrice and
                COALESCE(p.color,'NULL')= COALESCE(b.color,'NULL') order by plantcode;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try and use `COALESCE()` to assign a zero value to those cases where a `null` is found otherwise:

```
SELECT  p.* FROM plant p
inner JOIN(SELECT Color, min(COALESCE(price,0)) minPrice
            from  plant group by color                                          
        ) b on COALESCE(p.price,0) = b.minPrice and
                COALESCE(p.color,'NULL')= COALESCE(b.color,'NULL') order by plantcode;
```

This is just a "fast shot": In the results you will find `0`s for the column minPrice and `null`s for the column `price`. The `COALESCE()` function makes them "equal".

Comment: It's not working, It is still not showing the null color

Comment: You need to use the coalesce on both join conditions. If the p.color and b.color are null, set them to a text value like 'NULL' that can be joined on. I edited this answer but it may not show up yet (awaiting peer review).

Comment: @Jeremy: yes, thanks for the edit! I simply overlooked the `color`-business ;-)